# When command `Brew install python@2` then error - `Theme error`. How to resolve?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

When
`brew install python@2`

Then occurs error:

```
==> make html
Last 15 lines from /Users/oleksandr-yefymov/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python@2/05.make:
writing output... [ 98%] whatsnew/2.1
writing output... [ 98%] whatsnew/2.2
writing output... [ 98%] whatsnew/2.3
writing output... [ 99%] whatsnew/2.4
writing output... [ 99%] whatsnew/2.5
writing output... [ 99%] whatsnew/2.6
writing output... [ 99%] whatsnew/2.7
writing output... [100%] whatsnew/index

generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages... download index
Theme error:
An error happened in rendering the page index.
Reason: TemplateNotFound()
make: *** [build] Error 2

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

When: `brew doctor`

Then: `Your system is ready to brew.`

OS - `Mac Mojave`

Any ideas what is that and how to resolve?

Comment: Wow.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: try to install newer version of Python

Comment: Ensure xcode command line developer tools are installed: `xcode-select --install` and then try reinstalling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this same problem.

What I did was

```
$ brew install --debug --verbose python@2
```

At the HTML failure point, I reached this:

```
debrew.rb:11:in `raise'
BuildError: Failed executing: make html
1. raise
2. ignore
3. backtrace
4. irb
5. shell
Choose an action: 2
==> Cleaning
```

I chose (2), Ignore - And the setup continued as expected.

Comment: Works also in case of upgrading `python@2` version, I used command `brew upgrade --debug --verbose python@2` and did the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and solved it with ignoring `make html` step, under CentOS7 with linuxbrew.